# How to tell if dragged contents is text or files during Javascript dragenter event

Tags: javascript, file-upload, drag-and-drop, dom-events

Using the **dragenter** event I show a dropzone on the webpage to have dropped files upload quickly, and it all works well. However, the dropzone also pops up when dragging selected text. How to tell the difference early on?

1. I know that the drop event exposes all file contents to be iterated using dataTransfer.files, but that's too late. I need it at dragenter, only I see the files array to be empty at all times.
2. I need full control over look & feel I am not looking for an existing lib.
3. I can see different values for **event.dataTransfer.Clipboard.effectAllowed** when dragging text versus files, but values also differ per browser (Chrome vs FF).
4. MooTools is in place, if that helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, I made enough progress to get differentiating working in Chrome and Firefox (3.6+). It's probably not foolproof but in case anyone might find it useful, here's the code:

```
  var isFileTransfer = false;
  if (evt.dataTransfer.types) {
    for (var i=0; i<evt.dataTransfer.types.length; i++) {
      if (evt.dataTransfer.types[i] == "Files") {
        isFileTransfer = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: If the OP ever comes back, please mark this as the answer. It worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to determine if a file was being dragged into the browser from outside, versus an image being dragged from within the browser window. I did it by listening for **dragstart** on the **document** object.  When a file is dragged into the browser from outside, the **dragstart** doesn't fire. So, if it does fire, it means something within the same page is being dragged.

```
document.addEventListener('dragstart', function() {
    samePageDrag = true;
}, false);

document.addEventListener('dragend', function() {
    if (samePageDrag) {
        samePageDrag = false;
    }
}, false);
```

With this, you can check the value of samePageDrag after a **dragenter** or **dragover** event to determine if the thing being dragged is from outside the browser or not.

Comment: I found I needed to add another listener for the 'drop' event in order to clear the 'samePageDrag' variable correctly, but this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

See docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/types

> If any files are included in the drag operation, then one of the types will be the string Files.

This is a one line solution

```js
// returns true if dragged item is not a file
// returns false if dragged item is a file
event.dataTransfer.types.indexOf('Files') === -1
```

```js
// returns true if dragged item is a file
// returns false if dragged item is not a file
event.dataTransfer.types.indexOf('Files') !== -1
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a small function to detect files dragging.

```
function isFileTransfer(evt){
    return [].some.call(evt.dataTransfer.types,function(t){return t=="Files";});
}
```